# Reloading page on deployed website shows 404 not found, while localhost works

Tags: ssl, https, localhost, hosting

I've deployed a React Redux site on hostgator.com. While it works to visit the page and navigate as usual. (React routing works), it shows 404 not found whenever I reload the page.

I talked to their support which, before leaving 20 sec into the conversation, came with the suggestion that it may have to do with the site trying to run on https, while no SSL is implemented.

I'm curious, why does it work locally and not on the world wide web? Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into a Server Side Rendering solution. A good framework for doing so with React is [Next.js](https://zeit.co/blog/next4).

Basically as long as you don't refresh the page React-Router has control over the address bar as well as history via the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History). But when you hit refresh you send a request to the server for whatever is in the address bar. But the server is not handling your routing, React-Router is on the client side. You also won't be able to type a child route directly into the address bar without server side rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean next.js in combination  with react router or next.js as a replacement of react router?

Comment: Yup, together react-router will handle client side routing and Next.js will generate routes that are handled server-side. It's not as daunting as it seems. Check out the example [here](https://zeit.co/blog/next2)

Comment: I havent thought about running a node server, since all my data is stored in firebase real time database. Is it possible to run a simple node server on the same folder as client side in HostGator? (or equivalent)

Comment: Unfortunately no, since the browser does not provide an interactive shell environment where you can spin up a server (though that would be cool). Host gator offers VPS hosting allowing you to run your Node server for $20/mo. I like Digital Ocean, less expensive $5/mo depending on how you configure it, and gives you access to a Virtual Machine where you can run your server.

Comment: Cool, what about conditional rendering, it that possible to achieve in node?

Comment: Could one consider the node file as the new "app.js component". Meaning - when I render each component, can I send each relevant function with its component just as I did in App, etc?